# Showing another form in VB

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a program with many forms in VB, I need to make a button that opens another form.

```
form2.open()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply the code will be

```
form2.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Do not use the default instance of the form(as has been shown in the other answers), instead

```
    Dim foo As New Form2
    foo.Show()
    'or
    'foo.ShowDialog()
```

If you want to show multiple instances of the same form this

```
    Form2.Show()
    Form2.Show()
```

will not work.

This will

```
    Dim foo As New Form2
    foo.Show()

    Dim bar As New Form2
    bar.Show()
```

Comment: Totally agree!  Default instances are evil!

Answer (score 2):

You can open a form inside yours as a MDI child, or you can "open" your new form in a new window with this methods:

```
form2.Show()
form2.ShowDialog()
```

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) about them.

Answer (score 1):

As SysDragon already mentioned,

```
.Show()
.ShowDialog(owner)
```

are the methods you can use.
If the calling Form should be frozen until the new opened one is closed again, then you should use ShowDialog.